# I am trying to increment when increment button is pressed but I am getting [object HTMLParagraphElement]1

Tags: javascript

I am working on this increment function when the increment button is pressed that should add +1 to count element.
This is my html:

```html
<p id="count-el">0</p>
<button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>
```

JS:

```js
let countEl = document.getElementById('count-el');

function increment() {
  countEl.textContent = countEl + 1;
}
```

Comment: where is your `count-el` element? If it's not defined, then how you are expecting to getting any value from it?

Comment: `countEl.textContent = Number(countEl.textContent) + 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a variable and then increment that variable in your increment function.

```
let count = 0;
let countEl = document.getElementById('count-el');
countEl.textContent = count;

function increment() {
  count++;
  countEl.textContent = count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a 'count' variable to maintain count and display it after every increment.
Or parse the number in the inner text to int and add.

This should work:

```
let countEl = document.getElementById('count-el');

function increment() {
    countEl.textContent = parseInt(countEl.innerHTML) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```js
let countEl = document.getElementById('count-el');
let count = 0;
function increment() {
  count++;
  countEl.textContent = count;
}
function decrement() {
  count--;
  countEl.textContent = count;
}
```

```html
 <p id="count-el">0</p>
 <button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>
 <button id="increment-btn" onclick="decrement()">DECREMENT</button>
```

Comment: for decrement i had tried this before: function decrement() {
    countEl.textContent = count--;
}
but before decrementing it would add 1 number then decrement. Do you know why?

Comment: this method works good for both incrementing and decrementing.

Answer (score 1):

It is widely considered bad practice to use inline event listeners. Instead, use `EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener` like this:

```js
const countEl = document.getElementById('count-el');
const incrementBtn = document.getElementById('increment-btn');
const decrementBtn = document.getElementById('decrement-btn');

function increment() {
  countEl.textContent = Number(countEl.textContent) + 1;
}
function decrement() {
  countEl.textContent = Number(countEl.textContent) - 1;
}

incrementBtn.addEventListener('click', increment);
decrementBtn.addEventListener('click', decrement);
countEl.textContent = 0;
```

```html
<p id="count-el"></p>
<button type="button" id="increment-btn">+</button>
<button type="button" id="decrement-btn">-</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the counter value in your element, you do not need to maintain it *globally*.

```
function increment() {
  const countEl = document.getElementById('count-el');

  // Validates the current counter value, Defaults to 0
  const count = parseInt(countEl.textContent) || 0;

  countEl.textContent = count + 1;
}
```